# psycopg2 module is not recognised

Tags: python-2.7, module, psycopg2

I have defined a module that uses psycopg2 module to query something from db.

When I import this module into my code, for some reason the name error:  `NameError: global name 'psycopg2' is not defined`

Module query is:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd

def queryRedshift(query):
    conn_string = """db details"""
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)              
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    data = pd.DataFrame(records)
    data.columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
    conn.rollback()
    cursor.close()
    return data
```

and the implementation:

```
import queryrs as qrs
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

query = """Some query"""

df = qrs.queryRedshift(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a long shot but I had the same problem when I installed psycopg2 to Python3 installation instead of Python2. And vice versa. You might wanna check where the real location of the module is.

Comment: I thought that too but it works fine when I define queryRedshift function locally...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using anaconda and have python version 3.8 or higher the following code works:

```
conda install -c anaconda psycopg2
```